# Search in Listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a textbox1 for finding “subject” in Listbox Control, Listbox will get “subject” from the textbox2, for example, I add “java1”, “java2” and “html” into Listbox Control and when I type the word “java” into textbox1 then the Listbox Control will only show everything which included “java”, for instance  :

In this case, there are “**java 1**” and “**java 2**”. Beside that, if I deleted the word “**java**” which is typed in textbox1, then the Listbox Control will show all of "subject" of it.

There has been the same question on this forum but the different in mine is that I have Data available in Listbox.

I try to change the Code for my case, but it’s not working.

This is my Code

```
Private Sub Tbx_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tbx_seach.TextChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
        If item.StartsWith(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.Clear()` then `For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items`. Btw, see the [ListBox.FindString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstring) method.

Comment: You need to store the elements of your ListBox OUTSIDE of the ListBox at FORM level.  This way you can iterate over them and only add what you want to the ListBox.  Otherwise, how would you "restore" all of the elements when a filter is cleared?  If you're simply storing strings, then use something like `Private elements As New List(Of String)` to hold your items.

Comment: @Idle_Mind  i used 'Private elements As New List(Of String)' it's work when i have 
data available in listbox , and i tried to change the code for case Data add from textbox but it's not work .

Comment: You need to show us your changes and how the data gets into the List(Of String) in the first place.

Comment: @ĐứcThắng, `ListBox1.Items.Clear()`, you clear your Listbox Control. How do you expect finding results when the Control is clear from searchable items ? You need to find another way to add your **Items** to your Listbox Control as mentioned by @Idle_Mind

Comment: @Idle_Mind Okay  I understood the problem, so my question is not possible?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use a **datatable** to store all listbox items then use the [RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8) property to refresh the listbox whenever the value of `textbox1` changes. Sounds like you need a simple `LIKE` clause. Or you could use LINQ.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm just a newbie in vb.net so i think maybe it's hard to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Idle_Mind Okay I understood the problem, so my question is not
>   possible? – Đức Thắng

Good grief...that's not what I said at all.  Try something like this out:

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private elements As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        elements.Add("cat")
        elements.Add("caterpillar")
        elements.Add("catfish")
        elements.Add("lion")
        elements.Add("lionfish")
        elements.Add("dog")
        elements.Add("lizard")
        elements.Add("bird")

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(elements.ToArray)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tbx_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tbx_search.TextChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If Tbx_search.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(elements.Where(Function(x) x.StartsWith(Tbx_search.Text)).ToArray)
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(elements.ToArray)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: LIke I said before, I can do with the data available in the listbox but my program needs to add data directly from the text box TT.

Comment: To add from the textbox, `elements.Add(tbx_search.Text)`, then Clear() and add everything back in as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

When i type in tbx_search to find , all data in my listbox was deleted(maybe hidden)

```
Private elements As New List(Of String)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    elements.Add(Tbx_type.Text)
    Lb_ListDK.Items.AddRange(elements.ToArray)
End Sub

Private Sub Tbx_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tbx_search.TextChanged
    Lb_ListDK.Items.Clear()
    If Tbx_search.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        Lb_ListDK.Items.AddRange(elements.Where(Function(x) x.StartsWith(Tbx_search.Text)).ToArray)
    Else
        Lb_ListDK.Items.AddRange(elements.ToArray)
    End If
End Sub
```